# Run an excel macro after every update

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel 2013 workbook with multiple sheets. On one sheet, I have a macro that show the formula in cells E7:E999. It works fine except for 2 things.

1. I would like to have the macro automatically run every time a user enters a new formula in the range noted.
2. I only want this macro to run for the one sheet named "PP" but right now if I run the macro it runs on any sheet.

Here's the macro I currently have. It does what I want, it just doesn't do it automatically and it runs on any sheet. I'm new to VBA in Excel so if you could give a few more details to your answers that would be most helpful.

```
Sub ShowFormulas()
Dim DQ As String, mesage As String
Dim rng As Range, r As Range

DQ = Chr(34)
Set rng = Range("E7:E999").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

For Each r In rng
   mesage = DQ & r.Formula & DQ
   r.NumberFormat = mesage & ";" & mesage & ";" & mesage & ";"
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Look into worksheet_change and Worksheet_Calculate events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Support has this:
[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213612][1]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

    ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
    ' changed.
    ' Place your code here.
    MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

End If
End Sub
```

You may also need to place the VB code within the code section for the worksheet (as opposed to general). Alternatively, narrow the parameter  target to include only the desired sheet.

Comment: In your intersect function you do not need the `Range(Target.Address)` just `Target` will suffice.  It is a range and does not need to be called with the `Range` keyword.

Comment: True; I was actually copying MS code from its webpage to give the example.  My own code did just as you suggested.

Comment: Typical MS, doing it in a way that is more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: Actually, my new code does not work so well...I will try to fix it in a bit.

Comment: Well, I said I was new so..... if I double click on the PP sheet (in the VBA window), there are 2 drop down lists. the first one has General and Worksheet. Which one of those do I select? Then, based on selecting General and Worksheet, the list of options in the 2nd drop down change. What do I select there?

Comment: I messed around and got this working automatically and only in the one PP sheet so I'm really excited and THANKS for all the help!

Comment: It turns out that when the formulas are showing if I insert or delete a row, the formula's don't dynamically updates. So I need to have the ability to switch back and forth between showing formulas or showing the results. I can use the original VBA to show the formulas but how do i switch back to results so I can insert / delete rows and have my formulas update correctly?